# use a tag html on onclick javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

Hi im having a problem with a tag in HTML, i want to use the a tag to call a java script function that i have on a folder js where i have all my javascripts. i already tried looking for answers but i didnt find any answer that could solve my problem. i know that the function is working because if i try it using an input onclick insted of the a onclick it is working, However in terms of aesthetics the a tag works better. i have this code

this is my function which is in a a folder /myProject/Source Files/js

```
function formhash(form, password) {
    // Create a new element input, this will be our hashed password field. 
    var p = document.createElement("input");

    // Add the new element to our form. 
    form.appendChild(p);
    p.name = "p";
    p.type = "hidden";
    p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);

    // Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent. 
    password.value = "";

    // Finally submit the form. 
    form.submit();    
}
```

and my HTML page has this:

```
<div class="user_login">
    <form action="includes/process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">
        <label>Email / Username</label> <input type="text" name="email" /> <br /> <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/> <br />

        <div class="action_btnns">
            <div class="one_half">
                <a href="#" class="btnn back_btn"><i
                                            class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i> Back</a>
            </div>
            <div class="one_half last">
                <a  class="btnn btnn_red" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password)">Login</a>
                <!--<input class ="btnn btnn_red" value='Login' onclick='return formhash(this.form, this.form.password);'-->
             </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <a href="#" class="forgot_password">Forgot password?</a>
</div>
```

If i press the button login, in my page nothing is happening. Please if you could help me it would be great, thank you

Comment: you should learn about and use [EventListeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) properly.

Comment: Are you loading the file with the function at all? Your browser won't automatically find the right files on the server. Did you look in the console (F12) to see if you got any runtime JavaScript errors?

Comment: @GolezTrol i did what you suggest and i get an error this.form is undefined. however why when i use the input i the function works correctly

Comment: use submit button instead of href .and take the id of form it will automatically submit your form.

Comment: There is no `this.form` in your code, so that error must be somewhere else, but it could be relevant. If the form is not found, it's also not possible to append a child to it.